# HTTP Status 404 on Eclipse (Mars) + Apache tomcat 8.0 + Apache CXF 3.1.3

Tags: eclipse, tomcat8

I am using Tomcat 8.0 But when trying to run the application (http://localhost:8080/example1/services/Calculator) in URL, I always prompted with HTTP status 404. 
1. I went to the Tomcat server 8.0 properties and changed the location to    "*tomcat 8.0v localhost server*".

2. I also double clicked the **Tomcat Server** and changed the server locations to "*Use Tomcat Installation*".
3. I copied the ROOT folder and paste into my project folder(proj folder.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0).

Yet the result is the same as in the image here.[HTTP Status error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMz9s.png)

I would be grateful to see a helping hand on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your web.xml to include the following

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>YOUR-APP-NAME</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The / in the **url-pattern** will tell Tomcat to look for any URL in your application root folder (you can change your project name to match that of your home directory). For instance, if you want to access your application at http://localhost:8080/Calculator, then rename your project in Eclipse to Calculator.

Now you just need to parse the actual URLs passed to your servlet (in doGet and doPost methods)

E.g.

```
   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
        response) throws IOException, ServletException  {   

    String url = request.getRequestURL().toString();
    String page = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/"));

   if("some_page".equals(page)){
    //do something
    }else if("some_other_page".equals(page)){
    //do something else
   }else{
      //open default page
      getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/Home.jsp").forward(request,    response);  
 }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response dsp_user. I included the code above in my web.xml source but it generated an error "starting tomcat server at localhost has encountered a problem" on the start of the tomcat. And the server will failed to run. Can you suggest another pls. Thanks.

Comment: Please, post the entire stack trace

Comment: I am running an add Web services based on Youtube video; like this code;- - - - - - - - -                     package com.inty.server;

import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://server.inty.com/", endpointInterface = "com.inty.server.endpoint1", portName = "CalculatorClassPort", serviceName = "CalculatorClassService")
public class CalculatorClass implements endpoint1 {
 public int add(int a, int b)
 {
  return a+b;
 }

} the web.xml file contained;